# unable to get response from web service where my url works good in browser

Tags: ios, iphone, json, web-services

i am using this url "[http://test.ccsplinfo.com/services.svc/addSubscriber?userdetails={Email_Id:mishra.bn@gmail.com,FirstName:BN,LastName:MISHRA,MobileNumber:8285547554,Password:mypass}](http://test.ccsplinfo.com/services.svc/addSubscriber?userdetails=%7BEmail_Id:mishra.bn@gmail.com,FirstName:BN,LastName:MISHRA,MobileNumber:8285547554,Password:mypass%7D)" to get data from server. But i am not getting any response. when i am just copy and paste
    this url to browser then getting true response.it means url working good but i am getting mistake in my code my code is here..

```
  NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setObject:@"mishra.bn@gmail.com" forKey:@"Email_Id"];
    [dict setObject:@"BN" forKey:@"FirstName"];
    [dict setObject:@"MISHRA" forKey:@"LastName"];
    [dict setObject:@"8285547554" forKey:@"MobileNumber"];
    [dict setObject:@"mypass" forKey:@"Password"];

 NSString *PostUrl=@"http://test.ccsplinfo.com/services.svc/addSubscriber?userdetails=";

 NSError *serr;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                        dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&serr];
    if (serr)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error generating json data for send dictionary...");
        NSLog(@"Error (%@), error: %@", dict, serr);
        return;
    }
    // Create request object
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:PostUrl]];

    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody = jsonData;
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setValue:
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",
      (unsigned long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *r, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!data)
         {
             NSLog(@"No data returned from server, error ocurred: %@", error);
             NSString *userErrorText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                        @"Error communicating with server: %@", error.localizedDescription];
             return;
         }
         NSError *deserr;
         NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization
                                       JSONObjectWithData:data
                                       options:kNilOptions
                                       error:&deserr];

         NSLog(@" responseDict :%@", responseDict);

     }];


Thanks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request look fine. I think you would be getting below error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840

JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.
```

It's because server is responding with invalid JSON object.